# Opinion on creating Business layer on migration of legacy sytem

Tags: c#, java, c++, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

> **I want an opinion from technocrats,**
>
> We are migrating legacy system build in Oracle forms using Oracle 8i
>   database. Client wants to  redevelop this legacy system in web
>   application so we choose MVC3 framework. Client wants us to re use all
>   stored procedures of legacy system,  which contains business logic of
>   application.
>
> If every business logic is written in stored procedure than i think we
>   don't need a Business layer in our system.
>
> So i created three layers -:
>
> Interface Layer -> MVC 3 application
>
> Data Layer -> Used to fetch information from stored procedure
>
> DTO Layer -> Used to transfer data from Interface layer to Data Layer.
>
> I did not created Business object or business layer , since all
>   business logic is inside Stored procedures. I don't like creating
>   business layer who just forward request from Interface layer to data
>   layer and don't have any business layer in it.

**Is this approach is correct ?**

Comment: I assume by Business layer you are meaning the Controller of MVC?  Whereas the SP may have some logic, things like validation, navigation etc would be better off in the Controller.  If you choose a Framework like Spring MVC, Struts, StripesFramework etc. you will need to use this layer. I hope this is what you were asking.

Comment: No, Business Layer something where we put all business logic, we never put business logic in Controller. Business layer is separate project

Comment: Sorry Business Logic can mean different things to different folk.  For example validation is something I call business logic.  Sometimes I put this in Javascript, sometimes in the servlet and sometimes in the DB

Answer (score 0):

> Business layer is separate project

If the business layer is a separate project, I would focus on the portions which are part of the project. It is entirely reasonable to have an interface layer, with minimal business logic (usually validation logic) in a server side application.  You might want minimal business logic in the client to make it more responsive i.e. it doesn't go all the way back to the database to validate input.

You can have the business layer in the database (not that I would do such a thing), or in server side Java, or some of it in the client (not that I suggest doing that either to a significant degree)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you still create a business layer even if it just forwards all the operations to the stored procedures which are part of the data layer.

Since the client wants you to reuse all the stored procedures that have the business logic in them it also sounds reasonable that he will not want you to modify or add any more stored procedures. Events may occur that will require you to implement them differently or change the sequence of a business logic that you can then put into your business layer. Maybe you may need a business logic that is not data-centric - meaning it does not sound reasonable to have it in a stored procedure, like sending an email or coordinating with a third party system.